# How to get value from this array in vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, if-statement

I have a data called votes, i want to get value votes.voteDict.12
But 12 is a variable, that's a cat id get from api. And i want shop.poiId = 691904
How can i call it?

```
<v-if="shop.poiId === votes.voteDict.[catid]">
```

```
data: function () {
   return {
    votes:[]
   }
}
```

**Data**

```
"voteDict": {
    "12": [
      691904,
      649950,
      649031
    ],
    "13": [
      677267,
      686968
    ],
    "29": [
      545344,
      499690,
      431970,
      618904,
      510121
    ],
    "30": [
      618540,
      613464,
      632345,
      672805,
      654174
    ],
```

Thank you

I would like to know how to get this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the value 691904 stored in some variable depending on some condition as 12 contains "12": [691904,649950,649031]. Then you can try:

```
computed: {
    selectedIndex() {
        const idx = votes.voteDict[catid].findIndex(num => num === 691904)
        return idx === -1 ? 0 : idx
    }
}
```

Then change your if statement to

`<v-if="shop.poiId === votes.voteDict[catid][selectedIndex]">`

Again, the number (691904) in the computed property should be a variable set according to some condition or dependent on the result of an API call.

Comment: Please give me an upvote as well :P

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test for the `shop.poiId` value.  Also accessing "12" property of `votes.voteDict` would be like `votes.voteDict[catId]` where catId is the integer 12

```html
<div v-if="votes.voteDict[catId].includes(shop.poiId)">
```